# How to run an ansible playbook only if a group exists?

Tags: ansible

I wonder if anyone found a solution that would avoid displaying any warnings if an inventory group is undefined or empty.

I just want to make a section of the playbook run *if a group exists and is not empty*, **skipping without warnings** if not.

Please read https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/35255#issuecomment-388455001 and test alternatives because I spend a good amount of time trying to find a workaround for this issue.

So far I was not able to find any way to avoid the warnings when group is not defined.

Comment: is `import_playbook` with `when: groups[your_group_name] is defined` an option?

Answer (score 4):

I'm slightly unsure if I'm answering the right question, but here goes. I'm interpreting "if a group exists and is not empty" to mean "the currently executing host belongs to a certain group".

If you meant to ask something like "can I find out from the current host if any *other* hosts belong to a group that the current host does not belong to," or "can I run a playbook without errors when the hosts defined for some groups are unreachable," then I'm afraid this doesn't answer your question :)

But running a task based on whether or not the *current host* belongs to a group can be done with one of [Ansible's default vars](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#hosts-and-groups), <strike>`groups`</strike> `group_names`.

The following playbook contains two tasks, one to run a `debug` task when the current host belongs to the group `existent`, and one to run a debug task when the current host belongs to the group `nonexistent`. As the output shows, the first task runs and the second does not.

### hosts.yml

```
[existent]
localhost ansible_connection=local
```

### playbook.yml

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:
    - name: This command will run.
      debug:
        msg: "The group `existent_1` exists!"
      when:
        - "'existent_1' in groups"

    - name: This command will not run.
      debug:
        msg: "The group `existent_1` exists and this host is in it!"
      when:
        - "'existent_1' in groups"
        - "'existent_1' in group_names"

    - name: This command will run.
      debug:
        msg: "The group `existent_2` exists and this host is in it!"
      when:
        - "'existent_2' in groups"
        - "'existent_2' in group_names"

    - name: This command will not run.
      debug:
        msg: "The group `nonexistent` exists!"
      when:
        - "'nonexistent' in groups"
        - "'nonexistent' in group_names"
```

### Output

```
➜ ansible-playbook -i hosts.yml playbook.yml

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [This command will run.] **************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: The group `existent_1` exists!

TASK [This command will not run.] **********************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [This command will run.] **************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: The group `existent_2` exists and this host is in it!

TASK [This command will not run.] **********************************************
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: I believe `groups` contains *all* groups. `group_names` contains only those of which the current host is a member.

Comment: @DylanYoung You're right, thanks! I've updated my answer, though I think yours may answer the question better.

Comment: Now the OP has both options at their disposal :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will suppress the warnings or not, but it should accomplish the first part ("make a section of the playbook run *if a group exists and is not empty*"):

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:
  - name: "This command will only run if {{ group_to_test }} is a non-empty group that exists"
    debug:
      msg: The group 'existent' exists and contains hosts!
    when: group_to_test in groups and groups[group_to_test]
```

Give 'er a test and let me know if she works to suppress the warnings!

Obviously `group_to_test` must be replaced with a constant string or set as a variable/fact/default.